# Reading excel file whose format is not in row/coloumn manner in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, excel, file

I am trying to import the excel file whose format is not in row column order in asp.net 3.5

I tried to read the file using OleDBDataAdapter but it given me the error "External file is not in proper format" something like that..

So please give me solution if anybody have **how to read the random formatted excel file in asp.net with c# example.....**

Answer (score 0):

You can There are libraries that allow to read data from Excel files, regardless of their format.
Try [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

The intrinsic format of excel is row and column. You just can't have any other format. It can be the way data is formatted in your excel sheet. It could be pivot way or chart way of arranging data, but for excel it is row and column.

For connecting to excel please refer http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel. It might help you. Once you are able to connect to excel, understanding the data and making it work for you is your task. HTH